# Using pipes how to separate a string line for every comma delimiter into new line in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, compass-sass

I have table row data like,
"Decode Message: Header,Body,MessageID , 23453, 0XEF"

I need the output in html page as below in every new line

Decode Message: 
Header,
Body,
MessageID,
23453,
OxEF

So I am trying to find any example by using Pipes in Angular2. Is there any other solution other than pipes ?
Kindly provide if any solution in CSS,SASS or HTML

Answer (score -1):

```
@Pipe({name: split}) 
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val) {
    if(!val) {
      return;
    }
    return val.split(/[,:]/);
  }
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let m of message | split">{{m}}</div>
```